# How do I check many RAR files for corruption at once?

Tags: software-rec, batch, rar

I have more than 20 gigabytes of RAR files, of which some have been damaged.

Can anyone tell me how to find out which RAR files are corrupt without trying to extract each archive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [7-Zip](http://7-zip.org/), you can select multiple RAR or other archives and select **Test** in the 7-Zip File Manager to test the integrity of all of them.

Alternatively, you can enable 7-Zip's shell integration feature<sup>1</sup>, use Windows Search to find all of the RAR archives (in Windows 7, use the search string `type:rar`), then select all of the results of the search, right-click on the results, and under **7-Zip**, select **Test archive**.

---

<sup>1</sup>To enable shell integration, open the 7-Zip File Manager, select **Options** from the **Tools** menu, select the **7-Zip** tab, and check the **Integrate 7-Zip to shell context menu** check box.  Note that this requires administrator privileges; in Windows Vista and Windows 7, right click on the icon for the 7-Zip File Manager, click on **Run as administrator**, and click through the UAC prompt.

Comment: really thanks for answer / because of my reputation i can not vote up.

Comment: While Windows search can find and display multiple files, and you can select all, when you use the context menu to 'test archive', it tests only one file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit slow but works well for me. I open a dos window using command.com then change directory to winrar directory. Then type winrar t -r e:*.*  this is to test all files on e drive including sub directories. if you only want to check rar files then e:*.rar will check all rar files on e drive. I found this VERY useful because winrar nor 7zip seem to recognize cbr or cbz files as archives if you use the integrity tester in the regular program interface. Also being able to test all sub-directories at one go is helpful. All errors will be output to a temp file that you will need to copy and save. Backslash after the e: doesnt seem to be saved in the message.

Answer (score 0):

you can simple open winrar app then navigate to the folder, in which content many rar file then press shift + drag mouse to chose all rar file then click "test" function on menu of winrar program. it will check all file and list all corrupted files

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already have well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.